# applicationstate in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Application[""] to store a few lists of very small size. I would ideally set it at only place.. `Application_Start`... but is there a chance the data might get lost in middle and I might have to store these lists back in Application inside places other than Application_Start? If yes, should I be prepared for any kind of race condition?

Let me know if any other concerns you have about using application_Data (like scalability??)... but the size itself of the data I will be storing in it will stay very small.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but if the lists are being generated at runtime and then stored as Application variables, they will be lost when the app pool recycles. I'm not sure but I think that this can be resolved based. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294113/268667) for more details.

Race conditions do occur but they afaik that is managed by the Application. You could always use the `Application.Lock()` function if need be as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524922/httpapplicationstate-why-does-race-condition-exist-if-it-is-thread-safe)

Have a look at this MSDN article regarding [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4(VS.71).aspx#cpconapplicationstate) which is good read and addresses your concerns. In short, the following are regarded as issues to be aware of:

- Memory impact of storing something
- Concurrency and synchronisation
- Scalability implications of storing application variables
- Life-cycle implications of information stored in application state - not durable

Comment: yes I have read that MSDN article, but I still could not decide whether I should just go ahead with it or not.