# Is HttpApplicationState.RemoveAll() thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, .net, http-caching, httpapplicationstate

In my `asp.net` application, i want to cache some data in the `HttpApplicationState`.

My code to set the data looks like this:

```
 Application.Lock();

 Application.Set("Name", "Value");

 Application.UnLock();
```

When I read the documentation, it says that `HttpApplicationState` is implicitly thread safe. But on many blogs it's written that we should use `Application.Lock()` and `Application.Unlock()` while writing data to the `HttpApplicationState`.

On the other hand, I could not find any documentation which says that we should use lock while reading data from `HttpApplicationState` or while clearing it (using `Application.RemoveAll()`) method.

My questions are:

1. **Should not we take care of thread-safety when we are calling `RemoveAll`**? In my application, it's possible that one thread is reading a data from `HttpApplicationState` whereas other thread could call `RemoveAll`.
2. In this case when reading and clearing `HttpApplicationState` is possible from two different threads at the same time, should reading too not be thread safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the lock if you are doing more than one operation against the application state. In you case you are just doing one operation, so it's perfectly safe without the lock:

```
Application.Set("Name", "Value");
```

If you do more than one operation, and they rely on each other, you need the lock. For example:

```
Application.Lock();

string name = Application.Get("Name");

if (name == null) {
  Application.Set("Name", "Value");
}

Application.UnLock();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the RemoveAll is thread safe as it calls the Clear method internally.
The Clear method calls HttpApplicationStateLock.AcquireWrite and then calls the base.BaseClear and finally releases the lock.

Also have a look at
[HttpApplicationState - Why does Race condition exist if it is thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524922/httpapplicationstate-why-does-race-condition-exist-if-it-is-thread-safe)

Comment: 1. What if there is a situation when multiple threads are already 'reading' the HttpApplicationState when some other thread calls the 'RemoveAll'? Or other way round?

2. Even Application.Set() method acquires the lock internally. But still its recommended to use Application.Lock and UnLock. So for the similar reasons, why don't we need (or not recommended) to use the lock when we call RemoveAll?

Comment: The complete object is thread safe as stated by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx.

Just looking at the code using ILSpy, you will see that most of the operations have locks around them.

i.e.
public object Get(string name)
{
 object result = null;
 this._lock.AcquireRead();
 try
 {
  result = base.BaseGet(name);
 }
 finally
 {
  this._lock.ReleaseRead();
 }
 return result;
}